# Can't resolve spigot dependency in artifactory-snapshot

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifactory, bukkit

I want to deploy my maven project from Gitlab to my Artifactory server, but it always says

```
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.spigotmc:spigot-api:jar:1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from artifactory-snapshot: https://maven.***.dev/artifactory/gitlab/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD FAILURE
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Total time:  14.005 s
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Finished at: 2019-10-30T20:53:15Z
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal on project SpigotProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project dev.***:SpigotProject:jar:2.1-BETA: Could not find artifact org.spigotmc:spigot-api:jar:1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT in artifactory-snapshot
```

I think I should "import" spigot to my Artifactory server, but how do I do that? Or do I need to change my pom.xml?
I have these repositories

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>papermc-repo</id>
        <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And this dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried adding this to my repositories but it didn't work either

```
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>https://maven.***.dev/</url>
    </repository>
```

I even removed the distribution management, but still no luck

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>60aee0014b49-releases</name>
        <url>http://maven.***.dev/artifactory/gitlab</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to add a remote repository.